# How to do addition with BigDecimal values?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have list of web element there are totally 3 values in list of web element I want to do addition of that values in BigDecimal I have return following code

```
Public BigDecimal calculatebigdecimal{
List<WebElement> elementValues = driver.findElements(By.xpath(“xpath to element”));
String values;
BigDecimal elementValueTotal= null;
BigDecimal sum = null;
for(int i =0; i<elementValues.size();i++)
{
values = elementValues.get(i).getText();
elementTotal = new BigDecimal(values);
elementTota.plus();
}
return elementTotal;
```

Comment: I try to apply the same logic but still confused and not getting the correct answer

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab can you help me with above code ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the ArrayList with appropriate elements from Web Site.

```
  public BigDecimal calculatebigdecimal() {
    List<String> elementValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    elementValues.add("1");
    elementValues.add("2");
    elementValues.add("3");
    String values;
    BigDecimal elementValueTotal = new BigDecimal(0);

    for (int I = 0; I < elementValues.size(); I++) {
        values = elementValues.get(I);
        elementValueTotal = elementValueTotal.add(new BigDecimal(values));

    }

    System.out.println(elementValueTotal);
    return elementValueTotal;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the text from web element so can you clarify it how can I do addition of that string values ? @Ali

Comment: BigDecimal accepts String as depicted in the example above.

Comment: Ah so how to avoid duplicating and perform the addition?

Comment: Convert List to Set which will remove duplicates for you and perform addition. Research in SO how to convert List to Set.

Answer (score 0):

Bigdecimal is immutable, so you gotta reassign the element. See:

```
elementTotal = elementTotal.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
```

Remember to assign elementValueTotal to 0 before the for iteration.

Comment: It is adding one to my current value I’m not getting the total for example if my value is 10 this code make it 11. It is not the correct answer @Gui Alencar

Comment: So you want to add `elementTotal = elementTotal.add(new BigDecimal(values));`

Comment: It’s not working also @GuiAlencar

Comment: The texts you are getting are String numbers ? like "2" or "6" ?

Comment: I’m getting string like 22.89 or 35.00 like that

Comment: Did you assign elementValueTotal to 0 before the for iteration ?

Comment: Yeah that’s the problem I haven’t assigned the value on the declaration section. I keep it null instead of 0.00 so I assign it to 0.00 and its working as expected

Comment: I updated the answer according to our discussion

Comment: Thanks@GuiAlencar